# Meetup API using RoR. Getting NameError: uninitialized constant Event in the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, meetup

Looking for some help with the Meetup.com API I'm trying to add to my Rails app. My purpose is just to have a view of local meetups when you open the app.

Here is my code so far:

Routes.rb (at the bottom before the last 'end'):

```
root 'meetup#get_meetup'
```

meetup_controller.rb

```
class MeetupController < ApplicationController
  def get_meetup
    if params[:city] && params[:name]
      @Event = Event.new(params[:city], params[:name])
    else
      @event = Event.new("90034", "networking")
    end
  end
end
```

meetup.rb:

```
class Event
  attr_reader :city, :nam
  def initialize(city, name)

url = "http://api.meetup.com/2/events?key#{ENV["meetup_api_key"]}&group_urlname=Girl-Develop-It-Austin&sign=true.json"

    response = HTTParty.get(url)

    @event = response["event"]

    @city = city
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I tried to create a new event search using the params for the city and name (aka the event categories) in the rails console.

rails console: 
Event.new("Austin", "networking")

and it gave me the error NameError: uninitialized constant Event

**I'm still new to using third party API's especially with Rails so I haven't found too much information online about how to correctly get them to work. If someone could please give me some insight into why this isn't correct...or if theres a great article/website to help me with these please let me know!!

Comment: So. don't you use ActiveRecord?

Comment: I tried to use pry as well..not sure if that's what you mean but that didn't give me anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the server after copy pasting, personally never tried to use meetup api.

**controller**

```
Meetup.new(city, name)
```

**/config/application.rb**

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

**/lib/meetup.rb**

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

class Meetup

  attr_reader :city, :name
  def initialize(city, name)

    resp = RestClient.get("http://api.meetup.com/2/events?key#{ENV['meetup_api_key']}&group_urlname=Girl-Develop-It-Austin&sign=true.json")
    #or
    resp = RestClient.get("http://api.meetup.com/2/events", 
        { key: ENV['meetup_api_key'], 
          group_urlname: "Girl-Develop-It-Austin",
          sign: true
        })

    @event = JSON.parse(resp, { symbolize_names: true })[:event]

    @city = city
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Just a question, but why would the meetup.rb be in the lib folder? I had placed it in my models folder as a new model. Also, I am now getting this error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `meetup' for main:Object" I think another issue is I'm a bit unsure of what to name event or meetup. I've changed my variables to "meetup" as well as the file names...but that may be an issue.

Comment: I'm trying to follow a few guidelines as well as the documentation but its hard to know exactly what to do as a beginner using API's.

Comment: Also where exactly am i placing that config line in application.rb. It gave me an error when updating my db. (config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib'))?

Comment: @DianaBG what rails version do u use ? ill update my post

Comment: Thank you! I have version 2.3.1 @7urkm3n

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code into service object

Create a folder services inside app folder. Then move your Event class to service folder. Also in initialize method, a good practice is you initialize only the variable. For parsing creating another method.And lastly, you have done a spelling mistake which I have corrected

```
 class Event
      include HTTParty
      attr_reader :city, :name ##you have made a spelling mistake

      def initialize(city, name)   
        @city = city
        @name = name
      end

      def parsing
        url = "http://api.meetup.com/2/events?key#
             {ENV["meetup_api_key"]}&group_urlname=Girl-Develop-It-
             Austin&sign=true.json"
        response = HTTParty.get(url)
        @event = response["event"]
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your rails console using `reload!` also you've mentioned above meetup.rb file which includes

```
  class MeetUp #you need to change class name 
      attr_reader :city, :name
      def initialize(city, name)

      url = "http://api.meetup.com/2/events?key#ENV["meetup_api_key"]}&group_urlname=Girl-Develop-It-Austin&sign=true.json"

      response = HTTParty.get(url)

       @event = response["event"]
       @city = city
       @name = name
     end
   end
```

If your filename is meet_up.rb the class name must `MeetUp` not `Event` Please change your class name or else you can change filename as event.rb

You can not define model or inside class as different name I hope my answer will help you. Thanks

Class name should be `file_name_except_extension.classify`. Therefore it would be `'meet_up'.classify` i.e. `MeetUp` and not `Event`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've edited that as well as changed some other issues with my code and have gotten the new error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `meetup' for main:Object".

Comment: If it is your ActiveRecord(Model) you need to remove earlier created migration/model from the app/model and db/migration directory manually after that you can create another migration to create meetup.rb